# How to use printf with conditional arguments

Tags: bash, printf

I'm trying to print `file` if `$files` is 0 or 1 and `files` if greater than 1. What is the concise way to do this in bash?

I tried using 'printf' as follows,

```sh
files=13;
printf 'There are %s file%s' $files $(($files > 1 ? 's' : ''))
```

and as expected this doesn't work out.

Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: FWIW, in English the correct phrases are normally: "There are no files" / "There is one file." There contexts in which you might say "There is no file", but they are less common; in general, in such contexts you would expect the number of files to be zero or one.

Comment: The `?` operator only works in a math context. In a math context, all content is interpreted as a number. `s` isn't a number, so... well, there you are.

Comment: @rici Actually the phrase is not important. But I'm glad I made a mistake there. Otherwise you would not write your answer with the array method.

Comment: A solution which is quite a lot easier both for computers and internationalization is to pick a phrase which requires no grammar, such as `"Number of files: %i"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were just selecting between `file` and `files`, you could do this, although it's not as concise as one might like:

```
printf "The search found %d file%.*s.\n" $files $((files != 1)) "s"
```

But in the statement in the OP, you would also need to change `are` to `is` to maintain verb/object agreement. In this case, it is almost certainly easier and more readable to use a conditional, but you could use an array:

```
formats=("is %d file" "are %d files")
printf "There ${formats[files!=1]}.\n" $files
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a condition like this:

```
printf 'There are %s file%s\n' $files $( [ $files -gt 1 ] && echo "s")
```

With `$( [ $files -gt 1 ] && echo "s" || echo "")` we are opening a shell in which the values are checked. In case a condition is matched, `s` is printed.

To also handle the `is/are`, you can add another condition:

```
printf 'There %s %s file%s\n' $( [ $files -eq 1 ] && echo "is" || echo "are" ) $files $( [ $files -gt 1 ] && echo "s")
```

#### Test

```
$ files=0
$ printf 'There are %s file%s\n' $files $( [ $files -gt 1 ] && echo "s")
There are 0 file
$ files=1
$ printf 'There are %s file%s\n' $files $( [ $files -gt 1 ] && echo "s")
There are 1 file
$ files=15
$ printf 'There are %s file%s\n' $files $( [ $files -gt 1 ] && echo "s")
There are 15 files
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, if you want grammatically **correct** output ("are" vs. "is"), you can just as well write it out instead of trying to make do with a single line...

```
if [[ $files -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "There is 1 file."
else
    echo "There are $files files."
fi
```

Better to read, less chance of getting it wrong, and probably faster as well as it does only one test, and does not start subshells.

Answer (score 0):

Because `%b` format specifiers interpret backslash escapes you can still use `?` operator to substitute a single character.

```sh
$ files=1
$ printf 'Removed %s file%b\n' $files \\$(($files > 1 ? 163 : 0))
Removed 1 file

$ files=15
$ printf 'Removed %s file%b\n' $files \\$(($files > 1 ? 163 : 0))
Removed 15 files
```